"Reproducibility" of the Asymptotics of ODEs
I asked this question here but got no reply.

My question has its origin and is related to this problem in heat conduction but is more general in scope.
Let $\mathbf {f(x, u)}$ be a sufficiently smooth function of variables $\mathbf x \in \mathcal D_x \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbf u \in \mathcal D_u \subset \mathbb R^m$ such that

$\mathbf {f(0, 0) =0}$;
for a given fixed vector $\mathbf u=\mathbf u \in \mathcal D_u$ the equation $\mathbf {f(x, a)}=0$ is solved by $\mathbf {x =x_a}\in \mathcal D_x.$

Define a positive causal monotonic smooth function $p(t)$ as follows $p(t) = 0 \text{ for } t<0$ and $p(t) =1 \text{ for } t>\tau_0 \ge 0$ for some fixed risetime $\tau_0$. If using the Heaviside step function then $\tau_0 = 0.$
Now consider the following autonomous differential equation:
$$ \dot {\mathbf {x}} = \mathbf {f(x, u)} \tag{1}$$
where the excitation vector is defined as
$$ \mathbf {u} = [a_1p(t-\theta_1), a_2p(t-\theta_2),..., a_mp(t-\theta_m)] \tag{2}.$$
And, finally let us also assume that Eq. 1 has a solution for arbitrary amplitude vector $\mathbf a \in \mathcal D_u$ and starting values $0\le \theta_k \le \theta_0; k=1,2,..,m$ for some fixed $0 \le \theta_0$ so that asymptotically as $t\to \infty$ we have $\mathbf x(t) \to \mathbf {x_{a,\theta}}$ in which I have indicated that the asymptotic values of the solution may also depend on the starting instances $\theta_k$.
I am looking for a reasonably "large" set of function $\mathbf f$ for which we can state that under these conditions the asymptotic limit is independent of the values $\theta_k \le \theta_0$ if the fixed $\theta_0$ is sufficiently small. Ideally, I am hoping for a criterion stating that the order of switching in the excitations does not matter if the system is, say, Lyapunov stable or something like that.
If the matrix $\mathbf A$ is Hurwitz stable having all eigenvalues with negative real part, then for the linear equation of constant coefficients $\mathbf {\dot x = Ax + Bu}$ this type of "stability", or asymptotic independence on the starting instances, is true because all the transients will decay exponentially, but I would like to know if it can be shown to hold in some non-linear case as well. A simple perturbation scheme on the excitation does not seem to work because the amplitudes can be arbitrarily large.

It seems to me that what happens in the linear case is that $\dot x=Ax+Ba$ has a (unique) globally asymptotically stable equilibrium, namely $x=-A^{-1}Ba$. This will be the limit independently of $\theta$. The conclusion will be the same as soon as $\dot x=f(x,a)$ has a globally asymptotically stable equilibrium.

Thank you. I think you are right, but let us suppose we are not that lucky that there be a globally asymptotically stable equilibrium. Can then the asymptotics depend on the switching order?
